# OSX update cache: does it accumulate over time?

Tags: snow-leopard, disk-space

I bought my MBP 2.5 years ago, it came with a 240 GB drive. I don't remember how much free space it hat to start with, but let's just say 200 GB.

I mostly use it for personal use (different machine at work). I don't have movies/music stored on it (all on external drive) and have some applications installed (total app folder size: 20 GB). My ~ dir is also approx 20 GB.

My drive now says 140 GB free. I can't explain the 20 GB difference. I think apple isn't removing downloaded updates after installing. Where should I look?

Another idea was mail cache folder. Where is this folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you download a utility that shows the size and arrangement of your files. Personally, I use DaisyDisk. It is shareware, so for your purposes, it would suffice to trial the software.

Mail attachments are stored in `~/Library/Mail Downloads/`

It is unlikely that OS X is keeping packages after installation through Software Update. You should first look to your cache `~/Library/Caches/` and perhaps your sleepimage, which is located under `/var/vm/sleepimage` (note that the sleepimage is recreated every time the system goes to sleep. Read more about disabling it [here](http://my.bergersoft.net/2009/10/07/how-to-delete-the-hibernation-file-in-mac-os-in-recovery-mode/) if you are concerned with HD space).

DaisyDisk (or equivalent) will do a much better job at identifying where the "growth" has occured on your filesystem so that you may excise it than we ever could. I suggest you give it a try.

[image]

Comment: nice!! Could it be the sleep image accumulating? I never reboot/shutdown. Always use sleep mode

Comment: No. The sleep image does not steadily grow in size. The OS X sleepimage is the same size as the physical amount of RAM you have in your system. So if you have 2 GB, that's the size of the sleepimage. I suppose if you've upgraded to 8 GB, then you'd see a dramatic size increase but only in that scenario. You can read more about it here: http://osxdaily.com/2010/10/11/sleepimage-mac/ I mentioned it because it is often not looked at when people start tabulating HD space

Answer (score 1):

[Grand Perspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/) gives you a visual overview of what is taking space on your disk.

Try it:  it's free and open-source.

[image]